# RTF to HTML conversion using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I am a QT programmer and Cocoa is new for me. How can convert Rich Text Format(RTF text with images and hyper link) to HTML using cocoa under Mac OS X. I have rich text into a char type buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an NSAttributedString instance with the RTF data. Walk the attribute ranges of the string (this includes the attachments / pictures) and translate to HTML (append the proper HTML to an NSMutableString) as you go. This lets you convert any attributes you'd like while leaving behind those you don't want.

A helpful NSAttributedString method would be [-enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000166-SW2). Inside the block you can determine whether you want to handle or ignore a given attribute. See the [Handling Attachments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000164-155814) section for information regarding dealing with your images (considered an attachment in RTFD, just another attribute type for a "character" in the attributed string).

Answer (score 1):

Depends really on your output requirements… i could convert the string "hello world" to valid html, but it might not be what you were expecting… anyway as an alternative approach to @Joshua's…

The [textutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/textutil.1.html) utility can be useful for all sorts of conversions. You can use it from Cocoa via [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/textutil"];
[task setArguments: @[@"-format", @"rtf", @"-convert", @"html", @"-stdin", @"-stdout"]];
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
[task setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];
NSFileHandle *taskInput = [[task standardInput] fileHandleForWriting];
[taskInput writeData:[NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:cStringLength]];
[task launch];
[taskInput closeFile];
```

Synchronously

```
NSData *outData = [[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *outStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or async

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(readCompleted:) name:NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification object:[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading]];
[[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading] readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify];

- (void)readCompleted:(NSNotification *)notification {
  NSData *outData = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];
  NSString *outStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"Read data: %@", outStr);
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSFileHandleReadToEndOfFileCompletionNotification object:[notification object]];
}
```

Please don't just copy and paste this though.. it's just an example, not tested production code.

Comment: Wrapping external tools in an NSTask has a *lot* of potential pitfalls. There are code examples of my answer (using Cocoa classes directly) out there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the conversion of RTF to HTML using `NSAttributedString` and the additions to it provided by Application Kit - read [NSAttributedString Application Kit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html).

The are methods to create an `NSAttributedString` from RTF, such as `initWithRTF:documentAttributes:` and `initWithURL:documentAttributes:`.

To create HTML you can use `dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:` specifying appropriate attributes, you'll need to specify at least `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`.